# How to type a component with children prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass a wrapper component as a prop

I tried this:

```
type HeaderProps = {
  Wrapper: ReactNode;
}

const Header = ({ Wrapper }: HeaderProps) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <button>click me</button>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

But it results in an error:

```
JSX element type 'Wrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

Example wrapper component:

```
type SomeWrapperProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const SomeWrapper = ({ children }: SomeWrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
<Header Wrapper={SomeWrapper} />
```

or

```
<Header Wrapper={(props) => <SomeWrapper {...props} other={props} />} />
```

What should I replace `ReactNode` with to make it work?

Is there any other syntax to make things work like that?

Comment: how do you create this component?

Comment: You can use React.ElementType

Comment: `ElementType` works fine ✅

Answer (score 3):

I'd choose `FC` type. You could also pass your custom props to it if `SomeWrapper` accepts more props than `children`.

```
type HeaderProps<T = {}> = {
  Wrapper: FC<T>;
};

const Header = ({ Wrapper }: HeaderProps<CustomProps>) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <button>click me</button>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Changing `T = {}` to `T = { children: ReactNode }` makes it work as I wanted, thanks :)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski `children` is already built-in prop in `FC` type. Perhaps you could just remove the generic `T`? `type HeaderProps = { Wrapper: FC };`

Comment: It was optional originally in React 17, that's why I have to add it. I'm pretty sure that it's optional in React 18 as well